# Python program to manipulate a list based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this Python code:

```py
def main() -> None:
    print("Welcome To UltiList!")

    lst = []
    len_of_list = int(input("Enter the len of the list: "))

    while len(lst) <= len_of_list:
        print(">> ", end="")
        args = input().strip().split(" ")

        if args[0] == "append":
            lst.append(int(args[1]))
        elif args[0] == "insert":
            lst.insert(int(args[1]), int(args[2]))
        elif args[0] == "remove":
            lst.remove(int(args[1]))
        elif args[0] == "pop":
            lst.pop()
        elif args[0] == "sort":
            lst.sort()
        elif args[0] == "reverse":
            lst.reverse()
        elif args[0] == "print":
            print(lst)
        elif args[0] == "exit":
            print("Bye!")
            exit()
        else:
            print("That's not a valid command!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I thinks is very repetitive,Eg: In JavaScript I could do something like:

> ```javascript
> const commands = {
>   append: (arg)=>lst.append(arg),
>   remove: (arg)=>lst.remove(arg),
>   ...
> }
>
> // This would go in the while loop
> commands[`${args[0]}`](args[1])
> ```

And I would no longer have to make any comparison, this will make it more readable and shorter in my opinion.

What can be improved?

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'switch statement' is bad because you've chosen to not use the same algorithm as your JavaScript example:

> ```js
> const commands = {
>   append: (arg)=>lst.append(arg),
>   remove: (arg)=>lst.remove(arg),
>   ...
> }
> ```

Converted into Python:

```py
commands = {
    "append": lambda arg: lst.append(arg),
    "remove": lambda arg: lst.remove(arg),
}

commands[f"{args[0]}"](args[1])
```

Python has no equivalent to JavaScript's `() => {...}` lambdas.
So you can abuse class if you need them.

```py
class Commands:
    def append(arg):
        lst.append(arg)

    def exit(arg):
        print("bye")
        exit()

getattr(Commands, f"{args[0]}")(args[1])
```

Comment: `lambda arg:lst.append(arg)` is just a closure `lst.append`. F-string is an overkill, non-str aguments would not be found in dict keys. Else/default option can be done with `commands.get(args[0], None)` and adding `None:lambda print(...)` to `commands`.

Comment: @PavloSlavynskyy 1. The point is to show `lambda` exists in Python, not to cut characters. 2. I'm just copying the JS example in the question. 3. Yes, or you could just do `default = lambda arg: print(...)` `commands.get(args[0], default)(args[1])`.